# What Buddhist babies' names or meaning should be?

Tags: lay-buddhism, children, india

My relatives ask me to suggest good names that must be Buddhist.
I tried on internet but there are from other culture I want Indian names so what  names or meaning should be?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably start from the [Buddhist Dictionary of Pali Proper Names](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/dic_idx.html) and then find proper Sanskrit versions of the Pali names.

For example, the Pali name Sariputta is Śāriputra in Sanskrit. The full version of this name is known as Śāradwatīputra.

Answer (score 2):

How about these?

I'm not an expert in Sanskrit or Indian languages, so you better check these out carefully first. I'm also not sure about gender conversions, appropriateness and Sanskrit grammar.

- Dharmadhara (female may be Dharmadharini) - upholder of the Dharma
- Dharmānusara (female may be Dharmānusarini) - follower of the Dharma
- Dharmacāri (female may be Dharmacārini) - observer of the Dharma
- Dharma
- Dhārmika
- Karuṇā - compassion
- Mudita - sympathetic joy
- Maitrī (likely female) - friendly, benevolent
- Satya (likely male) - truthfulness, honesty (one of the paramis / paramita)
- Dāna (likely male) - generosity
- Śīla - virtue
- śīladhara (female may be śīladharini) - upholder of virtues
- Kṣānti - forbearance, patience
- śānti (likely female) - peace
- ānanda - bliss

Answer (score 0):

I have a male friend named Buddhi (meaning wisdom).

Answer (score 0):

This has a list but it's in Sinhalese 
https://mahamevnawa.lk/name-for-babies-baby-names/

Comment: This isn't helpful I don't know that language.

Comment: I'm sorry it isn't. It might be useful to someone else. If you're really keen, I need time to translate some for you..